# SVNError: File already exists: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException

Tags: java, svn

By code I was importing file to SVN repository like :

```
SVNCommitClient client = new SVNCommitClient(authManager,null);       
client.doImport(file,SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(<SVN Path>),  
  "Am ready to commit", new  SVNProperties(), false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
```

First time when adding files its being added and committed automatically but if I run the same code when files are already exsisting at the destLocation(ie,SVN Repo Location) following error is occuring :

```
ERROR : Failed to Download File.SVNException

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160020: File already exists: ....
```

Please help me to override the already exsisting files in SVN by JAVA code.

Thanks,

Rajhrita

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to import multiple times?  In theory, you'd import once and then you'd checkout a local working copy and subsequent changes would be committed through that.

The standard pattern would looking this this:
Import files
Checkout local working copy
Make changes and committ
Update from svn
Etc..

If you wish to import and then have subsequent changes made from that imported directory then I guess you could try a checkout to that directory after the import.  That might make all future modifications commits of adds and modifications.

Peter